# How to add a Strikethrough to Icon in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, strikethrough

I need to add a strikethougth in my `icon`. I read about custom strikethougth using padding but it is working on text

```
Container(
  child: _child,
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8), // this line is optional to make strikethrough effect outside a text
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage('graphics/strikethrough.png'), fit: BoxFit.fitWidth),
  )
```

How can I add it to this code?

```
Icon(
 Icons.list_alt,
 color: Colors.white,
)
```

**Edit 1**

I tried :

```
Container(
 padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
 child: Icon(
 Icons.shopping_cart,
 color: Colors.white,
 size: 200,
),
)
```

And it is not working

Comment: @someuser not working

Comment: it’s working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: StrikeThroughWidget(
            child: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart, color: Colors.orangeAccent, size: 200),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class StrikeThroughWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;

  StrikeThroughWidget({Key key, @required this.child}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: child,
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
      foregroundDecoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage('assets/strikethrough.png'), fit: BoxFit.fitWidth),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to use the asset. Thanks